# How can i Fix The "--search-engine" option does not exist in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a problem when i try to setup magento on my localhost. I already active the elasticsearch and my elasticsearch version is 7.6.0. So, what is the problem and how can i fix it.

The "--search-engine" option does not exist

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the elastic search hostname using a database or may set it using the below command.

php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7

php bin/magento config:setcatalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname <elasticsearch_hostname>

php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port <elasticsearch_port>